# Python File overwrite each time i added a new line

Tags: python

i am doing a program where the user can add a student from student.txt into a new .txt file  with a output like this

this is my content of student.txt

```
201707001 Michael_Tan
201707002 Richard_Lee_Wai_Yong 
201707003 Jean_Yip 
201707004 Mark_Lee 
201707005 Linda_Wong 
201707006 Karen_Tan 
201707007 James_Bond
201707008 Sandra_Smith
201707009 Paul_Garcia 
201707010 Donald_Lim
```

this is my code

```
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())

def askModule():
    module = input("Enter the module that you want to register to: ")
    print("Who you want to register into the module?\n\n")
    studentNumber = input("Enter student number: ")
    studentName = input("Enter student name: ")
    with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\210CTStudentModule.txt", "w") as f:
        with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt", "r") as f1:
            for line in f1:
                stdId, stdName = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
                if studentNumber == stdId:
                    if studentName == stdName:
                        f.write(module + " " + stdId + " " + stdName)
                        break
             else:
                print("Unsuccessful")

 askModule()
```

what i want my output to be

```
Module 201707001 Michael_Tan
Module 201707002 Richard_Lee
Module 201707003 Jean_Yip
```

but the output has been overwrite in only one line  even though i add the module 3 time

```
Module 201707003 Jean_Yip
```

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

`with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\210CTStudentModule.txt", "w") as f:`

to:

`with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\210CTStudentModule.txt", "a") as f:`

You are using `"w"` which overwrites any previous content. You need `"a"`, which appends to the existing file without overwriting.

Sometimes, users can get locked out of files which they open and write to in programs and then those files become `read-only` if they aren't closed. It's a good idea to add `f.close()` and `f1.close()` at the end of your `askModule()` function as you don't need to keep those files open any longer.

Comment: It should be noted that `with` will automatically close the file, no need to call `.close()` on it